# How can I move specific elements from one array to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm trying to sort out every string, that contains "INIT:" and put it into another array.

Here's my code:

```
for (j = 0; j < splitCode.length; j++) {
    if (splitCode[j].indexOf('INIT:') > -1) {
        noInit = splitCode[j].replace('INIT:', '');
        cmdList.push('{id:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:"'+noInit+'"}');
        splitCode.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
```

If it finds `INIT:` it sets `noInit` to the string without `INIT:`. Afterwards, it adds it to the `cmdList` array and removes the code from the other array. This works, but it only works once. For every following `INIT:` string it won't work.

Comment: Looks like a filter + map. Why do you want to mutate the original array?

Comment: I've tried your code and it worked as you said.. at the end I've two arrays, one containing only things that doesn't start with `INIT:` and the other with stuff that started with `INIT:` without the `INIT:`.. I might have misunderstood what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` reindexes the array, so removing an item will make you skip the next one. To avoid this, either iterate backwards, or use `--j`:

```
var splitCode = ['INIT:1', 'INIT:2'],
    cmdList = [];
for (j = 0; j < splitCode.length; ++j) {
  if (splitCode[j].indexOf('INIT:') > -1) {
    cmdList.push('Cmd:' + splitCode[j].replace('INIT:', ''));
    splitCode.splice(j, 1); // This reindexes the array
    --j; // Update the iterator index to reflect changes
  }
}
cmdList; // ["Cmd:1", "Cmd:2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is also ok.

```
var splitCode = ['INIT:1','INIT:2', 'Boru:5', 'INIT:3','INIT:4'],
      cmdList = [];
splitCode.forEach( e => !!/INIT:/.test(e) && 
cmdList.push('{id:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:"' + e.replace(/INIT:/,"") + '"}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ["INIT: one", "two", "three", "INIT: four"];
var array2 = [];

array1.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.indexOf("INIT:") == 0) array2.push(e);
})

array2 // <-- ["INIT: one","INIT: four"]
```